# DELETE from Oracle table with two self-referencing fields

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to deal with a table as follows (simplified version):

```
  CREATE TABLE "CE2"."TABLE1" (
      "ID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
      "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
      "TABLE1_1_FK" NUMBER(38,0),
      "TABLE1_2_FK" NUMBER(38,0),

      CONSTRAINT "PK_TABLE1" PRIMARY KEY ("ID", "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN") ENABLE,
      CONSTRAINT "FK_TABLE1_1" FOREIGN KEY ("TABLE1_1_FK", "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN") REFERENCES "CE2"."TABLE1" ("ID", "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN") ENABLE,
      CONSTRAINT "FK_TABLE1_2" FOREIGN KEY ("TABLE1_2_FK", "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN") REFERENCES "CE2"."TABLE1" ("ID", "SOME_IMPORTANT_COLUMN") ENABLE
  )
```

This table has a compound primary key and two self-referencing fields. Also, note that there's no CASCADE DELETE behaviour.
I would like to delete some records from this table given a set of primary keys. 
The child records referencing the target records (which are to be deleted) have to be deleted as well.

If I had had only one self-referencing field, for instance, TABLE1_1_FK, I would have written this:

```
delete from table1 where (id, some_important_column) in (
    select id, some_important_column from table1
    start with (id, some_important_column) in ((1, 'b'), (2, 'd'))
    connect by TABLE1_1_FK = prior id 
)
```

Please note that the schema can't be changed, and I would avoid changing the CASCADE behaviour (right now it's NO ACTION).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just adding `OR TABLE1_2_FK = PRIOR ID` in your CONNECT BY clause?

Comment: `connect by TABLE1_1_FK = prior id or TABLE1_2_FK = prior id`

Comment: Thanks @BrankoDimitrijevic and GriffeyDog - your solution does the job. On a side note, I forgot about the compound nature of the primary key, so the CONNECT BY clause now looks like: connect by (TABLE1_1_FK = prior id and some_important_column = prior some_important_column) or (TABLE1_2_FK = prior id and some_important_column = prior some_important_column). Could you please post an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Here you go:

Did you try just adding `OR TABLE1_2_FK = PRIOR ID` in your CONNECT BY clause?